# Describe quotient space

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I got stuck on this problem about describing quotient space. Hope someone can help me to solve this. Thanks a lot

> Let $X$ be topology space and $A \subset X$.Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the partition of $X$ which consists of the set $A$ and the one-point sets $\{x\}$ for all $x \in X - A$. Let $X \backslash A$ be the quotient space with respect to this partition. Describe $X \backslash A$, here:
>   
> a) $X = \{(x,y,z)\;|\;x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ and $A = \{(x,y,0)\;|\;x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$
>   
> b) $X = S^2$ and $A$ is  the equator in $xy$-place

I got confused when people try to describe quotient space using the intuition, like "imagining...". In my understanding, to describe a quotient space, we need to find a quotient mapping from the original space. So can we describe the quotient space using imagination without clarifying quotient mapping? Is there any chance that our intuition is wrong? Thanks for reading my question. I really appreciate.

Comment: There seems to be no topology on $X$ are we to assume that this is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$? Up to the topology when we see (a) we intuitively think that the quotient space should be a cone. To back up this intuition we need to construct the quotient mapping etc.

Comment: Quotient spaces generally work by "glueing". For example in part (b), we can imagine taking a sphere, and crushing $A$, which is the equator, to a single point. The picture is if the sphere was a balloon and we tightened a string around the middle. This would leave us with a bulge of two spheres above and below the scruched point. Can you try doing something similar for (a)?

Comment: @Nex: The problem first describes the general construction of identifying a set $A$ to a point and then asks what happens in two specific instances of this construction.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The first line says let $X$ be a topological space.... So I would have thought that $X$ in (a) and (b) should be a topological space?

Comment: @Nex: It is: it’s the given subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That is what I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: @Chanler: I see your point, let me try to build the quotient mapping by myself. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Nex: Yes, topology on $X$ is the subspace of $R^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a)$ For the sake of simplicity, cut the cylinder by above and by below in order to get a compact cylinder. Since the equivalence doesn't mess with those parts, it is obvious (prove it) that if we restrict ourselves to this part of the cylinder there will be no problem.

Now take the obvious continuous function from the cylinder to the "two-fold" cone with vertix on the origin. You get a induced continuous map from the quotient space to the cone. Since it is bijective and the cylinder we took is compact (! this is why we restricted. Compactness is good), it is a homeomorphism.

$b)$ Try to repeat the same reasoning as above (it is easier, we are already compact!). Hint: You should arrive at a homeomorphism with two spheres touching at a point.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your part a), why can we infer that the function is a homeomorphism if the cylinder is compact? As far as I know, we at least need to prove that the function is CONTINUOUS, too. Then if the domain space is compact and the range space is Hausdorff, then that function is homeomorphism

Comment: @leducquang It is continuous due to the universal property of the quotient topology.

Comment: Oh, So I guess that the quotient map for question a) should be: $f:(x,y,z) \rightarrow (xz, yz, z)$. For part b), I need to use spherical coordinate system with the mapping $f:(1, \theta, \phi) \rightarrow (|cos \theta|, \theta, \phi)$. Did I make any mistake?

Comment: In part $(a)$, that map looks good enough. In part $(b)$, you could do the following (and this would also work for part $(a)$):

Take the sphere and put it inside a cylinder. Consider the "projection" of the cylinder in the sphere: that is, the map that takes a point on the cylinder and maps it to the point on the sphere which is the intersection of the line that goes from the point of the cylinder to the axis of the sphere. It should be straightforward to get its explicit description and also to conclude that it is continuous.

Comment: I see your point. I assume that your explanation is for part a). I think for part b), we need to do the same as: Put 2 tangent sphere into the $S^2$, and create the projection map in the same way. My wonder is that: that construction is quite intuitive, so I guess we still need to show the function clearly and prove that it is continuous, right?

Comment: Yes. For that, you can proceed as follows: take $a=(x,y,z)$ in the cylinder, $b=(0,0,z)$ in the axis, consider the segment $at+(1-t)b$ and solve for $t$ in order to $at+(1-t)b$ to have norm $1$. This is quite similar to one way which you can conclude the expression of the stereographic projection.